# matlab normalized histogram

Tags: matlab, histogram

Hello I am trying to create an histogram of the variable Wkinet for various times j (it s how the energy distribution of some particles changes through time) but I want to 1)for every time step not take in to account the zero values 2)Take as a result all the histfits for every value of time in one diagramm but only the fit not the bars 3)I would also like it normalized on the y axes

```
 nbins=100;
for j=1:ntM

 idxToKeep   = Wkinet(:,j ) ~= 0;
   Wkinet2     = Wkinet(idxToKeep,:);
   y=Wkinet2(:,j).*erg2eV;
  histfit(y,nbins)
  hold on
    delete(h(2))% deletes histogram
     end
      hold off
   end
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include what the problem is with your current code (wrong result, error message, etc) and include also a simplified (shorter) version of your input data. See [mcve].

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
        erg2eV = 6.2415e11;
        ntM=500;
          myTolerance=1e-15; % in erg units.
        nbins=1000;
    for j=1:ntM/10:ntM
        hold on
     myFit = fitdist((Wkinet_eV(Wkinet_eV(:,j)>myTolerance, j) ), 'Normal');
         maxEv = max(Wkinet_eV(Wkinet_eV(:,j)>myTolerance, j)); 
         minEv = min(Wkinet_eV(Wkinet_eV(:,j)>myTolerance, j)); %also

            myX   = minEv: (maxEv-minEv)/nbins: maxEv; 
            myY   = pdf(myFit, myX);
            loglog((myX),( myY)); %maybe just plot or %plot(log10(myX),myY)
                  ylim([10^-13,1])
         pause;
   end
```